# I want to check if a value in csv exist in another csv file return 1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I have 2 csv files: one is `dictionary.csv` and the other one is `file.csv`, which contains a lots of words. I wanted to check if a word in `dictionary.csv` exists in a specific column of `file.csv`.

If it exists, a new file `new.csv`should be created. That file should  contain all data from file.csv but with one extra column that writes 1 if it exists and 0 if it does not exist.

These is the script I have:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

news=pd.read_csv("file.csv")

dictionary=pd.read_csv("dictionary.csv", squeeze=True)

pattern = '|'.join(dictionary)

exist=news['sentences'].str.contains(pattern, na=False)

with open('new.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for cols in exist:
        if pattern in exist:
            outFile.write(exist, "1")
```

As a result, I get an empty csv file, I guess I might have missed something.

```
file.csv
id      sentences
0        Roses are red
1        burgers are delicious
```

```
dictionary.csv
red
blue
green
```

The `new.csv` file should contain the following output:

```
id      sentences                exist/not exist
0        Roses are red               1
1        burgers are delicious       0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to create new column and [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to write result to a new file.

```py
news["exist/not exist"] = np.where(
    news["sentences"].str.contains('|'.join(dictionary), na=False),
    1, 0
)

news.to_csv("name.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given we have

```
file

   id              sentences
0   0          Roses are red
1   1  burgers are delicious
```

and

```
dictionary
       0
0    red
1   blue
2  green
```

You can do this:

```
words=list(dictionary[0])
file['exist']=file['sentences'].apply(lambda x: len([i for i in words if i in x]))
print(file)

   id              sentences  exist
0   0          Roses are red      1
1   1  burgers are delicious      0
```

and then you can save it:

```
file.to_csv('new.csv', index=False)
```